# AttributeError occurred in OpenAI and FAISS part: 'str' object has no attribute 'page_content'

Tags: nlp, chatbot, openai-api, langchain, faiss

I am loading my excel data from azure blob storage, the problem is when I fed my data to the model it answers a general data and not my custom data.
I can see the data clearly loaded from my terminal. however when testing the endpoint it does not answer according to my custom data. I tried to fix the subject error mentioned in my main title and "RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter", the code runs successfully and fixed that OpenAI and FAISS part: 'str' object has no attribute 'page_content' but it is answering public data not my custom data. And if I remove the "RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter" it will give the erro "OpenAI and FAISS part: 'str' object has no attribute 'page_content'".
I tried a lot on this but it seems like the components were not fed correctly to model.

code:

```
class MyBot(ActivityHandler):
    def __init__(self, conversation_state: ConversationState):
 
        # Initialize the BlobServiceClient with your storage account connection string
        try:
           
            connection_str = "from azure"
            blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_str)

        # Define your blob container and blob name
            container_name = "dataset"
            blob_name = "data.xlsx"

        # Get blob client
            blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)

        # Download blob content as string for csv or bytes for xlsx
            #blob_content_as_str = blob_client.download_blob().readall().decode('utf-8')
            blob_content_as_bytes = blob_client.download_blob().readall()

        # Convert the string data to pandas DataFrame
            #csv_buffer = StringIO(blob_content_as_str)
            #data = pd.read_csv(csv_buffer)
            excel_buffer  = BytesIO(blob_content_as_bytes)
            data = pd.read_excel(excel_buffer,sheet_name='Sheet1',engine='openpyxl')
            print(data.head(5))
            data = data.iloc[:,-2:]
            print(data.head(5))

        # Show DataFrame
            print(type(data))
           

        except AttributeError as e:    
            print("AttributeError occurred in Blob storage part:", e)
        
        try:
        # OpenAI and FAISS related code
 
            text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size = 1,chunk_overlap  = 0,length_function = len,)
            docs = text_splitter.create_documents(data)
            #logging.debug("Documents created: %s", docs)
            print(docs)
            print(type(docs))
            
            
            embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key='sk-key')
            print(type(embeddings))
            print("Embeddings initialized.")
    
            print("Creating vectors from documents...")
            vectors = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
            #print(embeddings.embed_query)
            print("Vectors created.")
            self.chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
            llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k', openai_api_key='sk-key'),
        retriever=vectors.as_retriever(), max_tokens_limit=16384, combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": QA_PROMPT}
            )

    
            print("Creating conversational retrieval chain...")
      
        except AttributeError as e:
            print("AttributeError occurred in OpenAI and FAISS part:", e)

**logs in terminal**: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
[Document(page_content='Q', metadata={}), Document(page_content='u', metadata={}), Document(page_content='e', metadata={}), Document(page_content='s', metadata={}), Document(page_content='t', metadata={}), Document(page_content='i', metadata={}), Document(page_content='o', metadata={}), Document(page_content='n', metadata={}), Document(page_content='A', metadata={}), Document(page_content='n', metadata={}), Document(page_content='s', metadata={}), Document(page_content='w', metadata={}), Document(page_content='e', metadata={}), Document(page_content='r', metadata={})]
<class 'list'>
<class 'langchain.embeddings.openai.OpenAIEmbeddings'>
Embeddings initialized.
Creating vectors from documents...
Vectors created.
Creating conversational retrieval chain...
Conversational retrieval chain created.
======== Running on http://0.0.0.0:3978 ========
```